# Memory leak situation when storing a URLSession task in a property in Swift

Tags: swift, memory-management, urlsession, retain-cycle, strong-reference-cycle

I'm trying to understand the memory leak situation in Swift language but there is a situation that I'm still wondering.

I've created a new UIViewController and call fetch function with storing the fetch task in a property without starting the task then I closed this UIViewController.

I found that the ***deinit function in this UIViewController is not called*** (Memory leak).

```swift
func fetchAPI() {
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { _, _, _ in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(self.view.description)
        }
    }
    self.vcTask = task
}
```

But If I call the fetch function with calling `resume` method and then I close UIViewController again.

I found that the ***deinit function in this UIViewController is called*** (Memory not leak).

```swift
func fetchAPI() {
    let url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!
    let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { _, _, _ in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            print(self.view.description)
        }
    }
    self.vcTask = task
    task.resume() // start downloading
}
```

For now I think that if I store a task in a property in UIViewController and I use `self` in the callback. It would create a cycle that caused Memory leak.

But when I call `task.resume()` Why the memory is not leak in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An un-`resume`d task will never execute its completion handler, because it will never complete. The task, and its handler, will therefore remain in memory.

We don't know the internal implementation of `URLSession*` but it would seem sensible for the framework to discard completion handlers once they are executed. This would break the retain cycle and allow the view controller to be deallocated.

You could confirm this by adding extra logging in the completion handler and deinit method - I would expect the view controller not to be deallocated until the completion handler has run.

Comment: Thank you, It really makes sense to me now that the framework will discard handlers after they are executed.

Answer (score 0):

(Adding to @jrturton's answer, which is 100% correct afaik)

This line of code

```
let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { _, _, _ in ... }
```

captures `self` strongly, causing the memory leak.

One way to avoid this is to change the capture to be `weak`, like so:

```
let task = URLSession.shared.downloadTask(with: url) { [weak self] _, _, _ in
    guard let self else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print(self.view.description)
    }
}
```

Alternatively, try adding `self.vcTask = nil` to the ViewController's `viewDidDisappear` method to manually break the cycle.

Comment: Another detail worth mentioning: if you only need that one particular view object, you can capture it instead of self: `{ [self.view] _, _, _ in ... print(view.description) }`, which circumvents OP's issues